# Adding glyphs to Fontforge

Tags: fontforge

When I open Fontforge to create a new font, it only lists a limited set of characters / glyphs. In the font I create, I need some glyphs that are missing from that default set, e.g. "single right-pointing angle quotation mark" (U+203A) and "single left-pointing angle quotation mark" (U+2039).

How can I add "slots" for these glyphs, or rather:

**What is the proper way to add glyphs that are defined in the Unicode table?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, well, just go to `Encoding > Reencode` and choose an encoding that contains the relevant slots.

Comment: There are red Xs over the new  encoding slot I added.  Choosing a different encoding gives more available spaces, but it does not remove the Xs.

Comment: thanks a lot! haven't seen such a terrible interface since sibellius <insert tantacrul reference here>

Answer (score 8):

Ah, well, just go to Encoding > Add encoding slot, then there will be a dialog to set how many slot(s) you want to add.